# Getting SQL result where common column value result count is more than 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table A and 4 column Product, Variant, Part, Order. Product, Variant may have same data but column Order is different. I want to find out of those rows where Order value occurs more than 1 for same Product, Variant data.

```
Product Variant Part    Order
------------------------------
ab        vb     a1       1
ab        vb     a2       1
ab        vb     a3       2a
ab        vb     a4       3
ab        vb     a5       4.1
```

Like above I want 1st and 2nd row as result because they have different Part but both have same order.

So, I want to search those entries which have same Product and Variant, and more than one part is placed on same Order So that I can manage the Ordering for such cases.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use exists logic here:

```
SELECT Product, Variant, Part, [Order]
FROM tableA a1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableA a2
              WHERE a2.Product = a1.Product AND
                    a2.Variant = a1.Variant AND
                    a2.[Order] = a1.[Order] AND
                    a2.Part <> a1.Part);
```

[image: screen capture of demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

you can `GROUP BY` `Product` ,`Variant` and `Order` and check for `count(distinct Part)` that is more than 1

```
; with CTE as
(
    SELECT Product, Variant, [Order]
    FROM   yourtable
    GROUP BY Product, Variant, [Order]
    HAVING COUNT(distinct Part) > 1
)
SELECT t.*
FROM   CTE c
       INNER JOIN yourtable t ON  c.Product = t.Product
                              AND c.Variant = t.Variant
                              AND c.[Order] = t.[Order]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT Rowid from tableName tblA where Rowid  in (select Rowid from tableName tblB group by tblB.Orderid having count(1)>1);
```